# Input aparece como print e não permite entrada de dados

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio-code

O objetivo do código a seguir é passar um valor recebido - por um campo de digitação(`input`) pelo usuário - por parâmetro em um método de uma classe no python:

```
aux = float(input('Digite o percentual desejado para reajustar o valor do salario : '))
print(str(dadosFuncionario.reajustarValorHora(aux)))
```

Ocorre que o texto dentro do `input` é impresso no output e não permite entrar com o valor.

Estou usando o VSCode e uma extensão Python Preview e lá exibe o seguinte aviso : User input is not supported. Este aviso não aparece como um erro de maneira comum.

A classe que estou chamando contém o seguinte código:

```
def reajustarValorHora(self, Reajuste):
    return 'Valores reajustados ' + ' = Ajuste do Valor/Hora Normal : ' + str(self.__valorHora * (Reajuste/100) + self.__valorHora ) +  ' Ajuste do Valor/Hora Extra : ' + str(self.__valorHoraExtra * (Reajuste/100) + self.__valorHoraExtra)
```

Quando eu passei o número por parâmetro, deu certo, o método retornou os valores corretamente mas quando tento com o `input` não é possível entrar com valor algum.

Answer (score 0):

Faça a conversão `string - inteiro/float` já dentro da função, importe o argumento `reajuste` como `string`.
Dentro da função quando invocar o parâmetro (reajuste) para cálculo faça a conversão para `float` ou `int`

Answer (score 0):

Ocorreu esse mesmo problema comigo e os passos que devem ser feitos são:

1- instalar a extensão CODE RUNNER

2- ir em arquivo/file

3- preferência/preferences

4- clicar em configurações/settings

5- na barra de pesquisa que será direcionado digite "code runner"

6- rolar a janela até encontrar "code-runner: Run in terminal"

pronto, já vai funcionar

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

No botão Run Code, em vez de clicar nele diretamente, clica na setinha que tem ao lado do botão e seleciona Run Python File. Desta forma, a função input ficará apta a receber dados do usuário.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Não precisa colocar float antes do input.
O python já reconhece o tipo de variável.
Tenta apenas aux = input('Digite o percentual desejado para reajustar o valor do salario : ')

Comment: Martinsdev, obrigado pela sua resposta mas tentei dessa forma e continua na mesma, faz um `print` do `input` e não permite entrar com dados.